# Excel nested formula with multiple if(isnumber(search)) criteria with AND/OR conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to modify the below formula to search for multiple text criteria, in the specific cell and returns the respective value if matches. It does only work if I use it for 1 criteria:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text2",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text3",A2)))),"Category 1","No")
```

I also need to include more criteria's in the same formula. I tried to use the below formula but it doesn't work correctly:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text2",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text3",A2)))),"Category 1","No") & IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text2",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text4",A2)))),"Category 2","No") & IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text6",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text4",A2)))),"Category 3","No")
```

How to modify the above to display the correct category number? I will need to add around 20 different categories in my formula.

Example:

[image]

Formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("London",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Luton",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cardiff",AH3298)))),"Category 1","No") & IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("London",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Luton",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dublin",AH3298)))),"Category 2","No") & IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("London",A2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Manchester",A2))),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Paris",AH3298)))),"Category 3","No")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe a data example of your input and expected output could help to understand

Comment: Thanks Foxfire And Burns And Burns. I added the example above.

Comment: After seeing your example, and because you said you got around 20 categories, and the formula you've posted works only for 3 categories, I think you are doing the wrong approach. Your final formula would be huge, probably. You have not posted what determines each Category (you should) but I think you should do a helping table in another worksheet with all categories, and then use an VLOOKUP to choose what category fits better.

Comment: That is not how you use OR. It should be `=IF(OR(something, something else, something else 2),If true, If false)`

Comment: Thanks Foxfire And Burns And Burns, instead of using this formula for 20 categories, I created a table in another spreadsheet and used a vlookup to get the required data. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have deduced your rules correctly, then the following might work for a straight formula approach (but see below):

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"London","Luton"},A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Paris",AH3298))),"Category 1",
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"London","Luton"},A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dublin",AH3298))),"Category 2",
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"London","Manchester"},A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cardif",AH3298))),"Category 3","No")))
```

However, for 20 categories, your formula would be about 2,000 characters long.

An approach using a Table, with clear-cut rules for your categorization, would be preferable as it should be much easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you Ron Rosenfeld. Indeed, that's the best solution. Instead of using this formula for 20 categories, I created a table in another spreadsheet and used a vlookup to get the required data. Thanks for you help